# Logic behind a proof in Topological Vector Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, self-learning, topological-vector-spaces

I found the following result at the beginning of some notes on topological vector spaces (TVS). This is a quite fundamental result, that apparently is considered the corresponding version of the triangle inequality in TVS. Here there is the result with two proofs.

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a TVS. Then, for every $W \in \mathcal{N}_0$ there exists a $U \in \mathcal{N}_{0}^\text{sym}$ such that $U+U \subset W$.
>
> *Proof 1:* For any neighborhood $W \in \mathcal{N}_o$, there are neighborhoods $U_1, U_2$ of $0$ such that $U_1 + U_2 \subseteq W$. The result follows by setting $U = U_1 \cap U_2 \cap (-U_1) \cap (-U_2)$.
>
> *Proof 2:* Since $0+0 = 0$ and addition is continuous, there exist neighborhoods $U_1, U_2 \in \mathcal{N}_0$ such that $U_1 + U_2 \subseteq W$. The result follows by setting $U = U_1 \cap U_2 \cap (-U_1) \cap (-U_2)$, by noting that $U$ is symmetric.

Here $\mathcal{N}_{0}$ denotes the neighborhood of $0$, and $\mathcal{N}_{0}^\text{sym}$ the symmetric neighborhood of $0$.

Now, in both cases I am not sure about the logic behind them.
In particular, here there are my doubts:

1) In *proof 1* how do we come up with the fact that there are neighborhoods $U_1, U_2$ of $0$ – and not of something else! – such that $U_1 + U_2 \subseteq W$?

2) In *proof 2* why do we focus on $0 + 0=0$? Is it because if we would have focused on – let's say– $2 + (-2) = 0$, we would have got still a neighborhood of $0$ by translation invariance, i.e. $\mathcal{N}_0 +2$?

As you could notice, both questions are fairly similar and are concerned, in my opinion, with the inner logic of TVS, that completely baffles me right now.

Thus, any feedback or help will be most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Because the addition is continuous at $(0,0)$ (being continuous), you can find a neighbourhood $W'$ such that $W'+W'\subseteq W$, and then, just take $W\cap W'$.

2)This exactly because for any neighbourhood $W$ of $x$, $-x+W$ is a beighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: First of all thanks. Regarding the first question, I am not completely sure I see the logic. In particular my problem is not with the fact that there are those neighborhoods (this is part of the definition of addition being continuous), but with the fact that those are exactly neighborhoods of $0$.

Comment: Regarding the second question, you mean that indeed my intuition about the role of translation invariance is correct, right?

Comment: For your first comment, see my edit. (This is definition of being continuous at $(0,0)$. For your second comment, your intuition is right,yes.

Comment: Thus the complete line of reasoning is: we can start from whatever $x, y \in X$ (e.g. $2$ and $-2$), it does not really matter, because we always end up by translation invariance to the case of $0 + 0 = 0$, and then we indeed have that we have those neighborhoods, because addition is continuous. Am I right? (sorry, I am really at loss)

Comment: Exactly, yes , you are right

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the addition $+: X \times X \to X$ is continuous is used.

Comment: First of all thanks. I think I will edit my question, because – in particular – question 1 is not simply why there are neighborhoods $U_1, U_2 \subseteq W$, but why are those neighborhoods –specifically – of $0$.